# Set up column names in a new data frame based on variable

Tags: r

My goal is to be able to allocate column names to a data frame that I create based on a passed variable. For instance:

```
i='column1'

data.frame(i=1)
  i
1 1
```

Above the column name is 'i' when I want it to be 'column1'. I know the following works but isn't as efficient as I'd like:

```
i='column1'
df<-data.frame(x=1)
setnames(df,i)
  column1
1       1
```

Comment: How exactly is that inefficient? What type of solution are you looking for?

Comment: I don't see much of a problem here.  Are you trying to save lines in an R script?

Comment: Often I'd rather write this all contained together - for example on a data.table:

`a='column1'`. To get the sum of column1: `sum(dt[,eval(as.name(a))])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to learn how base R works this way:

```
i  <- 'cloumn1'
df <- `names<-`(data.frame(1), i)
df
#  cloumn1
#1       1
```

Comment: Which is the same as `df <- setNames(data.frame(1), i)` which is what the OP had just in one line instead of two, although `setNames()` seems more readable. I still don't see how this is "more efficient."

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the answers posted by other users, I think you may be stuck with the solution you've already presented. If you already have a data frame with the intended number of rows, you can add a new column using brackets:

```
df <- data.frame('column1'=1)
i <- 'column2'
df[[i]] <- 2
df
column1 column2
1       2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to get rid of the `setNames`, you would probably never do this but

```
i <- 'column1'
data.frame(`attr<-`(list(1), "names", i))
#   column1
# 1       1
```

You can see in `data.frame`, it has the code

```
x <- list(...)
vnames <- names(x)
```

so, you can mess with the name attribute.

Comment: awwww yeah, in the finest traditions of replacing easy-to-read multiliners with obscure oneliners! +1!

Comment: @mathematical.coffee :D

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how you want it more efficient but you could add all the column names at once after your data frame has been assembled with `colnames`. Here's an example based on yours.

`data.frame(Td)
  a b
1 1 4
2 1 5`

`nam<-c("Test1","Test2")
colnames(Td)<-nam`

`data.frame(Td)
  Test1 Test2
1     1     4
2     1     5`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass the name of your column variable and its values as arguments to a dataframe, without adding more lines:

```
df <- data.frame(column1=1)
df
#  column1
#1       1
```