# Using variable in data.table group by clause

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a data.table that I am trying to summarise. This is my approach

```
library(data.table)

dtIris <-data.table(iris)
dt1 <- dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), 
              by=list(TrimSpecies = substr(Species,1,3),Petal.Length)]
```

I am wanting to be able to use a variable to identify one of the items to group by, I just can't get it to evalulate the variable in the list. It just treats it like a string and throws an error.

```
myvar <- "Petal.Length"
dt1 <- dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), 
              by=list(TrimSpecies = substr(Species,1,3),myvar)]
```

I have tried `noquote()`, `eval()`, `parse(text=)` all to no avail. Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `eval(parse(text=myvar))` or `get(myvar)` though that will name your grouping column `parse` or `get` respectively (then you could rename it).

```
myvar <- "Petal.Length"
dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), 
              by=list(TrimSpecies = substr(Species,1,3), eval(parse(text=myvar)))]

dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), 
              by=list(TrimSpecies = substr(Species,1,3), get(myvar))]
```

I am not sure how to do it in a way that preserves the name like you want it to. (Edit: `by=setNames(list(...), c('TrimSpecies', myvar))` - thanks @thelatemail!)

---

Edit - out of interest, in response to some comments below.

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
    eval=dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), 
              by=list(TrimSpecies = substr(Species,1,3), eval(parse(text=myvar)))],
    get=dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), 
              by=list(TrimSpecies = substr(Species,1,3), get(myvar))],
    chain=dtIris[, TrimSpecies := substr(Species,1,3)][,list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)),by=c("TrimSpecies",myvar)][,TrimSpecies:=NULL][]
)
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3 chain          100   0.151    1.987     0.250        0          0         0
1  eval          100   0.079    1.039     0.097        0          0         0
2   get          100   0.076    1.000     0.094        0          0         0
```

`get` is faster than `eval(parse(text=..)))` which is faster than defining `TrimSpecies`, using the character form of `by` and then removing it (chaining dts).

Comment: `dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), by=setNames(list(substr(Species,1,3), get(myvar)),c("TrimSpecies",myvar))]`

Comment: It's my favourite function for tidying things up when names aren't passed through.

Comment: I wish I knew about it yesterday - someone asked about initialising a dataframe `data.frame(myvar=1:3)` where `myvar` contained the name of the column, and if they could do this in one line. Someone came up with a bizarro command (I can't find the question again! lackaday!) `data.frame(myvar=1:3, '<-attr'=list(names=myvar))` or something arcane like that.

Comment: the `get()` is exactly what I was looking for. The `setnames()` is the icing on the cake! Thanks for a super solution.

Comment: You may avoid using `get`: `dtIris[, TrimSpecies := substr(Species,1,3)][,list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)),by=c("TrimSpecies",myvar)][,TrimSpecies:=NULL][]`

Comment: Yes, but this does modify the original `dtIris` twice (adding and then removing `TrimSpecies`) and has multiple chains, so I thought I'd leave it out.

Comment: `\`names<-\`(data.frame(1:3),myvar)`  versus `setNames(data.frame(1:3),myvar)` - I think one is clearly nicer :)

Comment: Someone should be doing benchmarking with different alternatives.

Comment: Out of interest, I did just that

Comment: @nongkrong don't get me wrong - I loved the bizarro answer! I've lost the link to that question, could you pass it to me? (apologies that this comment is fairly irrelevant to this question/answer, but I have no idea how to start a chat with you to ask instead)

Comment: hah, yea np, i erased taht answer tho, it just seemed too ridiculous, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577893/set-up-column-names-in-a-new-data-frame-based-on-variable/31578542#31578542

Comment: For arbitrary numbers of columns, the mget() function creates the list and names it for you, e.g. `byfields <- c("a", "b"); DT <- data.table(x=1:20, a=rep(1:2, each=10), b=rep(1:4, each=5)); summary <- DT[, sum(x), by=mget(byfields)]`

Answer (score 0):

The `by` statement does not accept strings.  It does accept variable references.

So instead of referencing the column name, you can make a variable copying the data of the column you want to aggregate by:

```
myvar <- dtIris[,Petal.Length]
dt2 <- dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), 
          by=list(TrimSpecies = substr(Species,1,3),myvar)]
all(dt2==dt1)
#TRUE
```

Comment: `by` can accept strings, for example `dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), by = "Petal.Length"]`. your solution works but doesn't solve the names issue, not to mention it make an unnecessary copy of a whole column.

Answer (score 0):

Things got a bit more tricky when I wanted to group by more than 1 variable at the same time. The way to proceed is to create a variable `myvar` with the names of the columns by which the grouping should be done (2, in this example); one can then use `get` twice in the following way:

```
dtIris[, list(AvgSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)), by = list(get(myvar[1]), get(myvar[2]))]
```